# Android Choose File To Upload - Issue With DOCs, PDFs, etc

Tags: php, jquery, android, upload

I have created a file uploader using jQuery and a hidden iFrame. This works in the browsers I need it to on a PC. However, when testing this on an Android phone I found the following problem. For simplicity I'm testing this with a simple file upload demo.

I am using the native internet web browser that comes with Android to open: http://encodable.com/uploaddemo/

I load the page in the browser and select choose file. This displays the applications on my phone which are capable of selecting files. I have Astro File Manager installed so this is the one I use. I have some test images and test documents. If I pick an image everything is fine and I can successfully upload the image. If I choose a document, it doesn't seem to be able fill in the location of the file properly (although it is filled in in the textbox) because when I click 'Begin Upload', it fires the error "please fill in the required items" as if a file has not been selected.

The only difference I can see is the paths that get used for an image versus a document:
-content://media/external/images/media/11484/image.jpg
-file:///mnt/sdcard/Test%20Files/pdf.pdf/

Perhaps permission related? I've also tried FileExpert and OfficeSuite to select documents but the same problem persists - is there another file browser that passes a different path?

File formats which work and use "content://": 'bmp', 'gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'
File formats that don't work and use "file:///": 'txt', 'rtf', 'doc', 'docx', 'pdf', 'tif', 'tiff'

Any pointers, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem relates to accessing the file path. Normally in jQuery you would use `$(this).attr('value')` or `$(this).val()` to get the file path value in the textbox. For my test example, with images that works fine and you can retrieve the file path but with documents you get nothing back. Odd. No idea why. This therefore means when POSTing the data via a form, nothing is submitted for a document and nothing gets uploaded.